# Query to select all rows containing a value that appears less than 8 times

Tags: mysql, count, having-clause

I'm trying to set up a system that has a parent and 8 children. I've done this by having a table of user_id and tier_id. Now I need to get a list of all the tier_id's that appear less than 8 times, so I know that tier is incomplete and then I can go to another list and get replacements.

```
SELECT * FROM tiers WHERE COUNT(SELECT tier_id) < 8;
```

I know this isn't right, but maybe it can help explain to a genius what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can build this into the INSERT too, to avoid race conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your query needs a `group by` clause, with which the `select` clause should be *consistent*:

```
select tier_id, count(*) cnt
from tiers
group by tier_id
```

This gives you one row per `tier_id`, with the count of corresponding rows. Then, you can use a `having` clause to filter on the count:

```
select tier_id, count(*) cnt
from tiers
group by tier_id
having count(*) < 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `HAVING` with `GROUP BY` clause.

```
 SELECT tier_id, count(*) as TotalCount
 FROM tiers
 GROUP BY tier_id
 HAVING TotalCount < 8
```

May be this will help you.